# Shape.FillFormat.presetTexture always shows -2 (msoPresetTextureMixed) even when set to msoTextureGranite

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I try to clone with a VBA macro the filling of an PowerPoint 2010 shape from source shape `sourceSh` to target shape `targetSh`; only the filling, otherwise `Shape.PickUp()` and `Shape.Apply()` would do.

Works fine for some cases like solid fill and gradient, but when the source shape is a built in texture like `msoTextureGranite` , then the poperty `Shape.Fill.PresetTexture` always returns `msoPresetTextureMixed`. So the following code crashes:

```vb
'sourceSh, targetSh initiallized before as Shape
'crashes, because the value of sourceSh.Fill.PresetTexture is msoPresetTexturemixed
Call targetSh.Fill.PresetTextured(sourceSh.Fill.PresetTexture)

'even this is unexpected..
targetSh.Fill.PresetTextured(msoTextureGranite)
'now the read only property targetSh.Fill.PresetTexture is expected
'to be a positive integer representing msoTextureGranite.
'instead I find -2 what represents msoPresetTextureMixed
```

Does any one knows a solution, work around, something else... ?

Comment: This is a known problem in any current and older version of PowerPoint. I’ve relied on OpenXml to extract the texture out in such a scenario. For a pure vba approach you could consider using the pickup/apply and then reseting the other properties like line formatting etc.

Comment: Thank you. Well, let's hope MS will fix it. I also had your Idea...just wanted to get around it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some more code to make the problem clear:

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Shape

    'let's assume, there is at least one shape on current slide
    Set sh = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes(1)

    Call sh.Fill.Solid ' make FillFormat solid

    Debug.Print sh.Fill.Type ' prints 1 (msoFillSolid)
    Debug.Print sh.Fill.PresetTexture ' prints -2 (msoTextureAlignmentMixed)

    sh.Fill.PresetTextured (msoTextureDenim)

    Debug.Print sh.Fill.Type ' prints 4 (msoFillTextured)
    Debug.Print sh.Fill.PresetTexture ' prints -2 again! (msoTextureAlignmentMixed)

    'This assertion fails, because sh.Fill.PresetTexture <> msoTextureDenim
    Debug.Assert sh.Fill.PresetTexture = msoTextureDenim

End Sub
```